# Which child process will inherit threads of parent process?

Tags: multithreading, operating-systems

What happens when one process has child threads and a child process, will child process inherit all child threads of parent process?

Assume OS is Linux. Let it be Java Threading model.

Comment: What OS? What threading model? Could you be a bit more specific in the situation you envision?

Comment: In what exact language? Using what library implementation for creating threads and processes?

Comment: @Michael, Let it be any threading model.

Comment: @AKS different threading models behave differently...

Comment: @Jimmy Can you please explain it to me for one threading model, so that it will give me some idea.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that the child process inherits one thread from the parent, namely the thread that had called `fork`.

This is from the Posix/Pthreads point of view. Linux usually tries to stay close to Posix so this also mostly applies to Linux, although Linux may have some features outside of Posix that behave differently.

One might ask why just one thread is inherited instead of all. Apparently an alternative call `forkall` was [considered and rejected](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) for Posix. At first glance this seems like it might be useful. Actually, though, it's easy to see how it could lead to intractable bugs. Consider a case where thread A has opened a file and is about to issue a write to it. At that precise moment, thread B calls `forkall`. Since thread A is duplicated in the child process, and (in general) all open files are duplicated in the child process, thread A and its clone in the child **both** write to the open file. This is most likely an error.

Even having the child process inherit just a single thread is problematic. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235516/fork-in-multi-threaded-program) and a good [blog article](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them) that it links to. The upshot is that there are issues but they can be dealt with.

The [Solaris Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/sthreads-99123/index.html) model, which predates Pthreads, had a different policy regarding fork and threads. By default the `fork` system call cloned **all** threads whereas the `fork1` system call cloned just the calling thread. Worse, when Pthreads was implemented in Solaris, the way the program was linked defined whether it was using Solaris threads or Pthreads semantics, which determined the semantics of `fork`. Very confusing.

Finally, you had asked about Java threads. The way a new process is forked in Java is using the `java.lang.Runtime.exec()` method. This fuses the functions of Posix `fork` and `exec`. In general, the subprocess need not be running a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), so none of the Java threads from the parent exist in the child. Even if the child does end up running a JVM, that JVM starts fresh by running the `main()` method of the start-class, and it doesn't inherit any threads from the parent.

Comment: Nice explanation. I'd just add that the Java's fused `fork` and `exec` is usable as neither `fork` nor `exec`. As you wrote, you can't access Java threads from it and you also can't replace the running process by another one (which would be nice e.g. for software updates).